# Screen Sharing using OPensips ,Blink and Sylk server

Tags: voip

I want to implement screen sharing using opensips , Blink and Sylk server utilities.

When I use msrp relay and opensips setup i get following errors:

> debug: session
>   y2tmlOfHnQHa3mBUxG50IzE0NTMyODY3OTcuNTQzOjE5Mi4xNjguNy4xNzU= for
>   1009@192.168.5.178 (UNBOUND): AUTH succeeded, creating new session
>
> debug: session
>   y2tmlOfHnQHa3mBUxG50IzE0NTMyODY3OTcuNTQzOjE5Mi4xNjguNy4xNzU= for
>   1009@192.168.5.178 (UNBOUND): Connection lost: Connection was closed
>   cleanly.
>
> debug: session
>   y2tmlOfHnQHa3mBUxG50IzE0NTMyODY3OTcuNTQzOjE5Mi4xNjguNy4xNzU= for
>   1009@192.168.5.178 (DISCONNECTED): bytes sent: 408, bytes received: 0

I suspect if we can use msrp relay for screen sharing as i just found IM and File share as the features in its documentation.

Can somebody help me with this implementation?

Can we use sylk server in the server setting option of blink client instead of msrprelay with 5061 port?